# How to add SQLite database to resources in a Qt project

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I can't add a database to resources:

```
#include "QtSql/QSqlDatabase"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":/new/prefix1/database.db");
    if (!db.open())
           qDebug()<<"ERRR"; // this line is printed at startup

    return a.exec();
}
```

the database is present in resources:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9koZc.png)

Comment: Since the resources are read only you may have to open the database in a read only mode. Is the data in the database never going to be modified?

Comment: @drescherjm _to open the database in a read only mode_ how to do this?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127409/is-there-any-qt-sqlite-plugin-for-storing-database-in-ram-by-vfs-for-loading-da](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127409/is-there-any-qt-sqlite-plugin-for-storing-database-in-ram-by-vfs-for-loading-da)

Comment: And: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254250/embedded-database-in-qt/4276580#4276580](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254250/embedded-database-in-qt/4276580#4276580)

Comment: @drescherjm it looks too complicated. Is there a way to just run open the database from the directory where the source code is located (main.cpp)?? After all, if you write `db. setDatabaseName ("database.db");` Qt will search for "database.db " in the build directory, not in the source code directory

Comment: There is no searching in the setDatabaseName() part. Although your program could instead use QDir to find the location of the file and use that as the argument to setDatabaseName().

Comment: This answer does not look complicated at all to me: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284020/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284020/487892)